# What prevents overflow in this system?

Tags: plumbing

I recently looked at this cooling system in a research lab.

[image: cooling system]

The heat exchanger (with chilled water hook-ups, not shown) pumps fluid over a wall to a heat load.  A transparent hose is attached to the heat load side to monitor the fluid level.

What prevents coolant from flowing down from the top of the wall into the heat exchanger and overfilling the reservoir?

What is the purpose of the valve?  Should it be open of closed for the water level monitor to work?

Comment: Not really a DIY question unless one is a mad scientist who uses one's home as a laboratory.  Entertaining question, though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a commercial cooling system not found in residential homes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this setup is somewhat hypothetical because the water level monitor would not be very useful as shown.  Disregarding that...

**Q:  What prevents [fluid] from overflowing the cooling reservoir?**

I agree at first glance this setup looks like it will function as a siphon and the fluid will drain to the bottom reservoir and out, but there are two key points that prevent that:

1. Most importantly, the lines connecting top and bottom tanks are connected to the *top* of the upper tank.  A void will appear under the connections to the upper tank as soon as the upper tank level recedes due to any water being drawn out.  The void will break the siphon.  Worst case is only the water in the lines will flow into the lower tank.  Then the flow will stop.  The lower tank has enough reserve capacity to accommodate the liquid in the lines.
2. Unless the upper tank is high enough above the lower tank to overcome the force of a vacuum (roughly 30 feet of elevation for water), the liquid will have difficulty leaving the upper tank if the upper air valve is closed.

**Q:  What is the purpose of the valve?  Should it be open for the water level monitor to work?**

I am going to answer these in the reverse of order asked.

1. The valve must be open for the water level monitor to work.  When the valve is closed, captive air in the upper part of the level monitor will have no place to go, hence water will be unable to enter or leave as the level in the upper tank changes.  Having the valve closed is as good as having the level monitor turned OFF.
2. What is the purpose of the valve?   That's a good question, and without more detail the best I can do is hazard a guess.  The upper tank is a heat source which is being cooled.  If the coolant gets hot enough to boil then it might be necessary to temporarily close the valve to prevent a mess of hot liquid sputtering out.  Judging from the trap placed in the line before the valve, I think that is a possibility.

Comment: Follow-up: What if the level monitor hose were partially evacuated of air?  (I have no reason to suspect this, but I'm curious anyway.)  I imagine that fluid from the upper tank would fill the level monitor and compress the remaining air until it reaches atmospheric pressure...

Comment: @higgy - I essentially agree, although I would not describe that situation as the air in the level monitor being "compressed."  Fluid from the upper tank would be drawn in until the gas pressure in the level equalized with the pressure behind the fluid.  Describing this as compression would be a misuse of the term.

Answer (score 1):

You have equal force pulling both legs of the loop downward; there's no opportunity for anything to flow except by pulling a partial vacuum) unless the pump drives it (which will be balanced) or the valve is open (to admit air) *and* the heat exchanger is lower than the cooling loop, as you show it -- which I strongly suspect it isn't.

In fact, for the level monitor to work, that has to be level with the top of the water in the reservoir, so I'm fairly certain that part of the diagram is wrong.

Comment: I can confirm that the heat exchanger _is_ lower than the cooling loop. Perhaps the hoses that connect to the cooling loop have enough slack to dip down below the heat exchanger - but I'm unable to check this.